# Gerador automático de Form's com innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um jogo de navegador pronto. É um jogo que somente coloca a resposta em um forma, se estiver certa, ganha pontos, altera uma imagem, bloqueia a caixa de textos e mais umas coisinhas. Em um v2 desse sistema, a minha ideia era um gerador automático dessas perguntas, por exemplo, eu tenho em outro arquivo varias perguntas e respostas, sei-lá, 60. Daí o sistema já vai criar esses 60 *forms* automáticos quando der *load* na pagina.

Eu estava tentando implementar como `innerHTML`:

```
function mais(campo) {
var i;
var k;
for (i=0;i<campo;i++) {
Linha1 = "<form method='POST' onkeyup='validar('0')' onkeypress='validar('0')' name='anime0'>";
Linha2 = "<div align='center'><img id='imagem0' src='fundo.png'/></div>";
Linha3 = "<audio controls preload='auto' id='playTune'><source src='music/001.mp3'></audio>";
Linha4 = "<div align='center'><br />Nome do Anime<br />";
Linha5 = "<input name='caixa0' type='text' id='caixa0' size='30' maxlength='30'/><br /><br /></div></form>";
Linha6 = "<input type='checkbox' name='itemName11' onclick='verificaChecks('11')' id='item34'/>Dica 1: (-1Pts)<input type='text' id='txt34' size='40' maxlength='40' disabled/>";
document.getElementById("Linha1").innerHTML+=Linha1+Linha2+Linha3+Linha4+Linha5+Linha6;

/Lá em baixo, no body:
<div id="Linha"  align="center">
</div>
```

---

Testei dessa forma e não foi. As caixa de texto funcionam. Porém nenhuma função em JS funciona. Como: `onkeypress='validar('0')' nem onclick='verificaChecks('11')'`

Eu fiz um teste colocando o form já no `body` e somente adicionando por `innerHTML` o resto do código. Daí a função do *form* funciona, porém o da *checklist* ainda não, provavelmente por ainda estar sendo inserido pelo `innerHTML`. Só fiz isso para testes pois eu preciso que o form se crie no `innerHTML`.

A impressão que dá é que quando é adicionado algum conteúdo, sendo *form's* ou *checklists* com funções na `div` pelo `innerHTML` as funções não encontram caminho pro arquivo `.js` como fora de escopo.

Comment: Esse javascript vai precisar de uma boa limpeza... Coloque a sua página toda e o que tem no `arquivo.js` que a gente ajuda a arrumar isso...

Comment: Index: http://pastebin.com/N52MScSb // Arquivo js: http://pastebin.com/D4EEcHtv

Comment: Imagino que terei que melhorar a estrutura então.. pra ser possível somente um form..?

Answer (score 1):

Estive a olhar o código e tens imensa coisa demasiado customizada. Devias ter código mais geral... menos customizado...

Não há problema em adicionar código dessa maneira. Melhor dito: adicionar dessa maneira não deve dar o erro que tens, mas há maneiras melhor de fazer isso...

Um exemplo da mesma funcionalidade: http://jsfiddle.net/27rrna3d/

O problema aqui são as aspas. Repara que estás a abrir a string com `"` e depois dentro da string a usar `onclick='verificaChecks('11')'`. Muda isso para onclick='verificaChecks(\"11\")'. Surge-me a duvida: porque não simplesmente `onclick='verificaChecks(11)'`? em formato de numero em vez de string?

Aqui ficam outras sugestões que imagino resolvam/ajudem o problema também.

Uma vez que estás a usar jQuery, em vez disto:

```
function verificaChecks(n) {
    numeroTemp = parseInt(n);
    if (document.getElementsByName("itemName" + n)[0].checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("txt" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 1)).value = arrayNomesAnimes[numeroTemp].dica1;
        desabilitaCheckBox("item" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 1));
    }

    if (document.getElementsByName("itemName" + n)[1].checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("txt" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 2)).value = arrayNomesAnimes[numeroTemp].dica2;
        desabilitaCheckBox("item" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 2));
    }

    if (document.getElementsByName("itemName" + n)[2].checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("txt" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 3)).value = arrayNomesAnimes[numeroTemp].dica3;
        desabilitaCheckBox("item" + (numeroTemp + numeroTemp + numeroTemp + 3));
    }
}
```

Podes usar assim e serve para todos os casos:

```
function verificaChecks(n) {
    numeroTemp = parseInt(n);
    $('[name="itemName' + n + '"]').each(function(i){
        var numero = 3*numeroTemp + i;
        if (this.checked){
            $('#txt' + numero).val(arrayNomesAnimes[numeroTemp].dica1);
            desabilitaCheckBox("item" + numero);
        }
}
```

No código que tens na pergunta podes subsituir:

```
function mais(campo) {
    var i;
    var k;
    for (i = 0; i < campo; i++) {
        Linha1 = "<form method='POST' onkeyup='validar('0')' onkeypress='validar('0')' name='anime0'>";
        Linha2 = "<div align='center'><img id='imagem0' src='fundo.png'/></div>";
        Linha3 = "<audio controls preload='auto' id='playTune'><source src='music/001.mp3'></audio>";
        Linha4 = "<div align='center'><br />Nome do Anime<br />";
        Linha5 = "<input name='caixa0' type='text' id='caixa0' size='30' maxlength='30'/><br /><br /></div></form>";
        Linha6 = "<input type='checkbox' name='itemName11' onclick='verificaChecks('11')' id='item34'/>Dica 1: (-1Pts)<input type='text' id='txt34' size='40' maxlength='40' disabled/>";
        document.getElementById("Linha1").innerHTML += Linha1 + Linha2 + Linha3 + Linha4 + Linha5 + Linha6;
    }
}
```

por isto:

```
function mais(campo) {
    var form = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < campo; i++) {
        form+= "<form method='POST' onkeyup='validar('0')' onkeypress='validar('0')' name='anime0'>";
        form+= "<div align='center'><img id='imagem0' src='fundo.png'/></div>";
        form+= "<audio controls preload='auto' id='playTune'><source src='music/001.mp3'></audio>";
        form+= "<div align='center'><br />Nome do Anime<br />";
        form+= "<input name='caixa0' type='text' id='caixa0' size='30' maxlength='30'/><br /><br /></div></form>";
        form+= "<input type='checkbox' name='itemName11' onclick='verificaChecks('11')' id='item34'/>Dica 1: (-1Pts)<input type='text' id='txt34' size='40' maxlength='40' disabled/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("Linha1").innerHTML += form;
}
```

Atenção que no código da tua pergunta faltava 2x `}` no código. E atenção também com ID duplicadas que não podem ser duplicadas...